# Get files between two dates in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to select files in a folder only between the first day in the current month and the last day in the current month. I tried:

```
$curr_month = (Get-Date -format "MM/01/yyyy 0:00:00")
$next_month = (Get-Date  $curr_moth).addmonths(1)
Get-ChildItem "\\logserver\C$\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGFILES\" -Recurse -include @("*.log") |
 where {$_.CreationTime -ge $curr_month -and
        $_.CreationTime -lt $next_month
        }
```

I get only the first log file and continue error:

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified network name is no longer available.

At line:3 char:18
+     Get-ChildItem <<<<  "\\logserver\C$\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGFILES\" -Recurse -include @("*.log") |
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (\\logserver\C$\WI...ES\WMI\RtBackup:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

The second problem: only from the first level of the path (no deep recursion).

Comment: There si possible solution, but want to know, what bad with first code...

    $curr_month = (get-date -format "MM-01-yyyy 0:00:00")
    $next_month = (get-date $curr_moth).addmonths(1)
     ls \\logserver\C$\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGFILES\*.log | where{               $_.CreationTime -ge $curr_month -and            $_.CreationTime -lt $next_month}

Comment: Shouldn't that be $_.CreationTime.Month in the where clause?

Comment: variable's name `curr_month` is a little bit confusing, but as you can see from line number 1, there si format MM/dd/yyyy (dd=01), so where clause is good. Strange is that error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$path = "\\logserver\C$\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LOGFILES"
$Include=@("*.log")
$cntDate = Get-Date

# First day of the current month
$firstDayMonth = Get-Date -Day 1 -Month $cntDate.Month -Year $cntDate.Year -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0

# Last day of the current month
$lastDayOfMonth = (($firstDayMonth).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1))

$firstDayMonth
$lastDayOfMonth

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse -include "$Include" |
 where {$_.CreationTime -ge $firstDayMonth -and
        $_.CreationTime -lt $lastDayOfMonth
        }
```

I tested it with another [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path and it works!
So the example you give `"C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles"` is accessible only to System.

Comment: thanks, but i have same error:
Get-ChildItem : The specified network name is no longer available.
Yes, output also give it. But this error suprise me...

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -recurse -ErrorAction Continue -ErrorVariable +gcierror` ... It should contain the paths of all folders that you do no have access to.

Comment: works perfect, you have right- access denied on subfolder... please, mark as answer. thanks.